# How to replace double quote with single quote from a string which contains HTML tags

Tags: javascript

I have following string which has double quotes inside HTML tags.

```
Have a "question" about xyz Web? <a href="https://xyz/yasd/aksda">Save time</a> before you get in touch with us.
```

I want to remove double quotes only if it exists in HTML tag inside a string.
I tried multiple regex to do so but have not find which will meet this requirement.

tried

```
var str = "parag here "aman"  <br style   = 'width:100px'/>   test link<a href=\"http://www\"></a>";
var regex = /<\w+\s*(\w+\s*=\s*(['][^']*['])|(["][^"]*["]))*\s*[\/]?>/g;
var rstr = str.replace(regex, function($0,$1,$2){
    return $0.replace($2, $2.replace(/'/g, '"'));
});
```

Expected output is :   `Have a "question" about xyz Web? <a href='https://xyz/yasd/aksda'>Save time</a> before you get in touch with us.`

Comment: _"I tried multiple regex"_, so, _what_ have you tried? What didn't work? Please add an [mcve]. Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to have those double quotes being replaced by a single code when it is within HTML tags? Using regex to find stuff within HTML is not the right solution because there are lots of HTML tags. There are probably a better approaches if you tell what your goal is (what do you want to do with the expected output string?).

Comment: I want to send this expected string to third party as it is required to them. @KarelG